# Debian package version comparing explanation

Tags: package-management, dpkg, packaging, versions

I'm a bit confused about the Debian package version orders.

Take a look at the following two  Debian package versions, how come the first is `<=` than the second?

```
0-emacs-29.1.90~202401142128~ubuntu20.04.1
0-emacs-28.3-rc1~202302201437~ubuntu20.04.1
```

I'm thinking that 29 > 28 so the first should be more recent, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [man deb-version](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/deb-version.7.html).

The string `0-emacs-29.1.90~202401142128~ubuntu20.04.1` parses as upstream version `0-emacs` with debian revision `29.1.90~202401142128~ubuntu20.04.1`.

The debian revision starts after the rightmost dash.

The string `0-emacs-28.3-rc1~202302201437~ubuntu20.04.1` parses as upstream version `0-emacs-28.3` and debian revision `rc1~202302201437~ubuntu20.04.1`.

Hence, the second is higher.